# Is there a way to limit the Object.keys function loop to the first 50?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a way to limit the keys.map(function (name) {...}.bind(this)); to the first 50.

```
var found = keys.length > 0;
if (found) {
  keys = keys.filter(function (name) {
    return name.indexOf(this.state.keypadValue) != -1;
  }.bind(this));

  items = keys.map(function (name) {
    var f = fLookupList[name];
    return (
      <div key={f.name} className="col-sm-7 col-md-7 navF">
        <button className="f button"
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }.bind(this));
}
```

I found this: this.props.data.slice(0, 5).map((item) => { but I'm not sure if it works for keys data object, I tried to implement it, and it didn't work.

Comment: If you are asking can you make `Object.keys` return the first 50 keys, then the answer is no, it will always return an array containing all the enumerable keys for a given object. The array is just a standard array of strings so, yes, methods like `slice` will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use slice to do this. ex)

```
key.slice(0, 50).map...etc
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to put the "data" before slice in my own attempt. I appreciate this!!